# Moving CSV files to talend ETL automatically

Tags: etl, talend

I am looking for a way to automatically apply the ETL process on csv files, as soon as new files are added to the folder. How can I use file watcher on talend ETL tool?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have **tFileProperties** component in Talend. This component has default schema like,

[tFileProperties schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwR9d.png)

In the above schema **mtime:** is for the timestamp indicating when the file was last modified. get maximum mtime and store in one global variable.

Implement the logic to get the no of newer files depends on new file mtime and old file mtime.

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tWaitForFile component to scan the directory and if, there are any files with the format provided in the component, it gets loaded automatically. Before that you need to have a logic to move the loaded files into separate archive directory else same files might get loaded again.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Thank you that is really helpful. However, how can I move files from a directory to another ? (I mean the already loaded ones)

Comment: Write an unix script to move the files. Make it on subjob ok

Comment: If you fee the answer is helpful, please mark it as correct answer, so that others can also be helpful